# Using where clause for arcgis analysis in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, where-clause

I am trying to write a python code for select analysis.

**FIPS**: column in feature *nameofinputfeature* whose values needs to be compared with **OFIPS**

**OFIPS**: variable whose value is known each time the code is run.

I am having a problem in syntax of the {where clause}

my code is:

```
arcpy.Select_analysis("nameofinputfeature", "C:\\a.shp", '"FIPS" = %OFIPS%')
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing modelbuilder (%OFIPS%) and arcpy. Are you saying your OFIPS is a variable that value comes from somewhere in say a loop? So it'll run multiple times and OFIPS value changes each time its run?

Comment: Yes, the value of OFIPS changes each time the loop is run, but I cant make it run even with a variable whose value is known (with no loop)

Comment: There are a lot of answers already in the previously mentioned gis.se post. However, simply change `'"FIPS" = %OFIPS%'` to `'"FIPS" = {}'.format(OFIPS)`  (assuming OFIPS is a variable in your code)